# How can I add a scroll bar on a chart from LighteningChart Library?m

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I'm currently trying to add a horizontal scroll bar below x-axis to control data displayed along x-axis.

The chart that I'm using is the following link.

https://arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0904-3dSpectrogramBox.html?theme=lightNew&page-theme=light
[3d Box Series Spectogram]

Unfortunately, there is not much information I can find on the API documentation about adding a scroll bar.

The closest api is 'setScrollStrategy' API.
Thus, I've added the following code snippet.

this.chart.getDefaultAxisX().setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategy.progressive)

But it didn't make any noticeable change..

If Anyone has similar experience to share with me to implement such functionality, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

At least I can say that there is no built-in functionality for this kind of scroll bar in 3D.

Programmatically you can alter the Axis interval like this

```
chart3D.getDefaultAxisX().setInterval(20, 40, false, true)
```

However, this is probably what you are after, since this just affects the positioning and scaling of the data, the samples outside this interval are not clipped out.

Connecting some sort of slider component to this interval would be straightforward, whereas adding this slider inside the 3D view under the X axis sounds tricky.